# Count the unique values after array Join in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have 3 columns as below

| col1 | col2 | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 12345 | 10 |
| abc | 12345 | 10 |
| bcd | 45689 | 15 |
| abc | 78945 | 20 |
| bcd | 54782 | 13 |
| def | 12345 | 10 |
| def | 12345 | 10 |

I looking to get result as below.

| col1 | col2 | count | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 12345,78945 | 2 | 30 |
| bcd | 45689,54782 | 2 | 28 |
| def | 12345 | 1 | 10 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` into [`array_agg`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#array_agg) with `distinct` and [`cardinality`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#cardinality) to count the length should produce required result:

```sql
WITH dataset (col1, col2) AS (
    VALUES ('abc', 12345),
        ('abc', 12345),
        ('bcd', 45689),
        ('abc', 78945),
        ('bcd', 54782),
        ('def', 12345),
        ('def', 12345)
) 

--query
select col1, 
    array_agg(distinct col2) col2, 
    cardinality(array_agg(distinct col2)) count
from dataset
group by col1
order by col1 -- for output ordering
```

Output:

| col1 | col2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | [12345, 78945] | 2 |
| bcd | [45689, 54782] | 2 |
| def | [12345] | 1 |

If you need different formatting for `col2` - use [`array_join`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_join).

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.
If I have col3 with prices for Col2 values. Can I get one more col in the result with sum of prices for col2 values? Like 12345 is $10 and 78945 is $20 then abc [12345,78945] 2 $30

Comment: I have accepted the answer. 
I am unable to figure out the array_sum, can you pls hlep, if you dont mind

Comment: @Nikhil `array_sum(array_agg(col2))` (or `array_sum(array_agg(distinct col2))`)? Not sure what is the problem. If this does not work can you add some actual values and errors you are getting.

Comment: i am getting error Function 'array_sum' not registered

Comment: @Nikhil are you using Athena? If yes (or just some older presto version) then `array_sum` can be unavailable and should be work around with [`reduce`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#reduce). Also since it seems you need "distinct" over the values also another approach will be required.